# How to fix the text inside the parent element so it wont expand beyond the parent element's width

Tags: html, css, positioning, parent

Help! How can I fix this? It's weird. I usually don't come up with this, but now it's so weird. What I know and expected is that it should not behave like that.
http://www.cssdesk.com/RfNvT

Comment: use `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `word-wrap:break-word`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/qJn8u/)

```
.container {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: segoe ui;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `overflow:hidden`, which will hide the overflow. This is assuming you don't want the text to wrap. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/qJn8u/1/)

There is also `overflow:auto` which will allow you to scroll through the overflow. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/qJn8u/2/)

Comment: Cool Thanks!
It is just weird, do you know what's the matter with that?
From all the time that I've been doing some html and css, I did all the same without `word-wrap: break-word` and it just automatically wrap according to its parent element. But this time, I don't know what happened. It's just, i don't get it..

Comment: yes thank you :) `word-wrap: break-word` is enough already to solve the problem

Comment: @user2975385 It is because there aren't any spaces.

Comment: Oh! Right! I forgot about that... hehehe, thanks! It was a great help..

Comment: yes i know hahaha, it just says that i have to wait some couple of mintues before i can accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would try updating your CSS to include:

```
.container h1 {font-weight: normal; margin: 0; overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Give that a go!